# jQuery element creation removes witdh and height when style attribute is ordered after width or height

Tags: javascript, jquery

After a very long search i have found this strange behaviour:

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/723xhcrf/

When you create an element with params the width and height (maybe more) are added to the style argument like so:

```js
$('<div>', {'width': '50px', 'height': '50px'});
```

Gives

```
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
```

But when you already have a style something strange happens based on the order of the keys of the params object.

```
$('<div>', {'width': '50px', 'style': 'background-color:blue;', 'height': '50px'})
```

gives

```
<div style="background-color: blue; height: 50px;">
```

And

```
$('<div>', {'height': '50px', 'style': 'background-color:blue;', 'width': '50px'})
```

gives

```
<div style="background-color: blue; width: 50px;">
```

What you see here is that the first width or height (maybe more) are overwritten by the style attribute that comes after it. I expect that both width and height in both cases are appended to the style attribute.

So my solution is to have a function that orders the params so that the style param is always the first key in the params object.

Does anyone know if this behavior is wanted or is this a bug in the jquery creation of dom elements?

Comment: Cant you pass a class name instead and put all of the above properties in the css file?

Comment: This is only a small part of the whole code that dynamically creates elements on the dom from the server. This part has no css file because the values can be filled in by the user itself.

Comment: The jQuery element creation API is confusing, it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you pass as the second parameter is not simply a set of attributes for the new element. They're more like implicit calls to jQuery methods. Only when the property name is not a jQuery method is it treated like a simple attribute.

Thus,

```
$("<div/>", { width: "100px" })
```

is effectively like

```
let div = $("<div/">");
div.width("100px");
```

So when you also add a "style" value, that *won't* be treated as a method call. Because of the way object property name ordering works, if that comes after your "width" property, it will overwrite the "style" value that the "width" implicit call established.

Really, the *right* thing to do to control styles is to use a "css" property:

```
$("<div/>", { css: { height: "50px", width: "50px", backgroundColor: "red" } })
```

You can also do things like set the content:

```
$("<div/>", {
  text: "Hello World",
  id: "some-id",
  css: {
    height: "50px",
    width: "50px",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
})
```